# How to extract data efficiently?

Tags: c#, linq

There is the next data structure:

```
var parents = new List<Parent>
{
    new Parent
    {
        Children = new List<Child>
        {
            new Child { Name = "Name1",  Value = 100 },
            new Child { Name = "Name2",  Value = 0 },
        }
    },
    new Parent
    {
        Children = new List<Child>
        {
            new Child { Name = "Name1",  Value = 0 },
            new Child { Name = "Name2",  Value = 200 },
        }
    },
    new Parent
    {
        Children = new List<Child>
        {
            new Child { Name = "Name1",  Value = 0 },
            new Child { Name = "Name2",  Value = 200 },
        }
    },
    new Parent
    {
        Children = new List<Child>
        {
            new Child { Name = "Name1",  Value = 100 },
            new Child { Name = "Name2",  Value = 0 },
        }
    }
};
```

Parents have the similar children but its values can be binary different (0 or some value).

The output should be:

```
var output = new List<Child>
{
    new Child { Name = "Name1",  Value = 100 },
    new Child { Name = "Name2",  Value = 200 },
};
```

Is there efficient and compact way to retrieve data in this way via LINQ or extension methods?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `The output should be` - why?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers are very close but they have small imperfections, in my humble opinion. Here's how I would write it:

```
var output = parents
    .SelectMany(p => p.Children)
    .Where(c => c.Value != 0)
    .GroupBy(c => c.Name)
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding but can't you just use `SelectMany` ?

```
parents.SelectMany(x=>x.Children).Where(x=>x.Value != 0).Distinct().ToList();
```

edit: Added .Distinct() per @GSerg's comment

Comment: Also `.Distinct()` I would assume.

Comment: `Distinct()` doesn't work here as is and still returns 4 items, if `Child` doesn't have custom equality comparison

Answer (score 0):

This avoids custom Equality operator or copies of your objects:

```
parents.SelectMany(p => p.Children).GroupBy(c => c.Name).Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault(c 
=> c.Value != 0)).ToList().
```